# Detect / Trace which version of Direct X is used / called?

Tags: directx

Microsoft Flight Simulator offers a Direct 10 Preview. How can I trace that the DX10 API is actually called, and no longer (only) the DX9 API. Is there a way (logs / tools) to trace this?

I want to find out whether DX10 features are really used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) should be able to show you that kind of information.

Comment: It does not show internal calls e.g.  IDirect3DDevice9::CreateTexture